# How can I rewrite in Swift this block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I need to rewrite an Objective-C block but I can't

This is the block in question :

```
[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFileList* files, NSError *error) {
        }];
```

In Swift, I tried :

```
service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLServiceTicket!,files:GTLDriveFileList!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
        })
```

But the compiler don't agree with that.

I tried :

```
service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLServiceTicket?,files:GTLDriveFileList?,error:NSError?) -> () in
})
```

But same issue.

And when I cmd+click on the class, I find :

```
// Clients should create a standard query with any of the class methods in
// GTLQueryDrive.h. The query can the be sent with GTLService's execute methods,
//
//   - (GTLServiceTicket *)executeQuery:(GTLQuery *)query
//                    completionHandler:(void (^)(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
//                                                id object, NSError *error))handler;
```

Does anyone knows how to made that ?

Thanks

Comment: `service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, object, error) -> () in /* ... your task comes here ... */ };`, maybe...?

Comment: Change `files:GTLDriveFileList` to `files:AnyObject!`

Comment: It works, but I need files to have the GTLQueryDriveFileList type, because after I need to use files.items.count, which is not present if files don't have a type.

Answer (score 1):

The completion handlers second parameter is an id object (obj c) so in swift it will become `AnyObject`

swift < 2.3 --

```
service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLServiceTicket!, object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!)->Void in

})
```

swift 3.0 --

since `id` parameter in objc code has `Any` type in Swift 3.0 hence --

```
service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket:GTLServiceTicket?, object: Any?, error: Error?)->Void in 

})
```

Comment: This answer does not have adequate information. Please add some context and/or explanation for your code snippet.

Comment: Hope it helps ,
Regards ,
Abhi